calculated average cycle per instruction (CPI) doesn't match sample output
I have the following information:
Number of ALU instructions: 90000 and number of cycles per instruction is 2
Number of Jump/Branch instructions: 30000 and  number of cycles per instruction is 4
Number of Load/Store instructions: 30500 and number of cycles per instruction is 6
Total number of instructions is : 150500
Average CPI is : (90000 * 2 + 30000 * 4 + 30500 * 6)/150500 = 3.209302326
However, in the sample output I have the CPI is : 3.202657
I think I'm missing something, any idea why my calculated CPI and the sample output CPI don't match?

What is "sample output"?
